# ParseException: mismatched input ')' expecting ',' issue

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Hi I learning pyspark with Jupyter myself. I have the CSV file in my local system and loaded in dataframe. I created the temporary table for this dataframe. While using the below code, I got the parse error. COuld you please help me out?

```
sqlContext.sql('select distinct(Eye color) * from superhero_table').show()
```

The error is shown below:
ParseException:
mismatched input ')' expecting ','(line 1, pos 25)

== SQL ==
select distinct(Eye color) * from superhero_table
-------------------------^^^

Comment: Presumably if `Eye color` is supposed to be a column name it needs to be quoted in some way, because it has a space in it.

Comment: @khelwood:sqlContext.sql('select distinct('Eye color') * from superhero_table').show() I used this as well but gave me syntax error as:File "<ipython-input-73-a1e83dc902e3>", line 1
    sqlContext.sql('select distinct('Eye color') * from superhero_table').show()
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I don't know what flavour of sql this is, but try with backticks. `\`Eye color\``. Or easier still, don't create column names with spaces in.

Comment: @khelwood :Thank you. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since your column name `Eye color` has a space in it, the SQL parser doesn't understand it's supposed to be all one identifier. You can quote it with backticks to make it clear.

```sql
`Eye color`
```

Or to make life easier, don't create columns with spaces in the name.

Comment: Sure. Actually I got the sample csv data online and used the same to create df and create temp table to load df data. Will certain consider that while dealing with these sort of columns. Thank You